# Changing strings to float variables in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, casting, 2d

I have a 2D array of strings called c. It has 3 columns. I want to make every 2nd column in each row a float type value. This is what I have so far

```
for row in range(len(c)):
   cNew = float(c[i][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I misread you question. Here's one solution:

```
array = [['string', '2.0', 'string'],
         ['string', '3.0', 'string']]

y = [ [float(x) if i%2 == 1 else x for i,x in enumerate(row)] for row in array]

print(y)
```

Comment: When I say every second column I mean ['string', float, 'string'] Thats why I have a c[][1] in my code

Comment: Ok, I changed the code, it was basically only the test if `i` is even to `i` is odd (and a bug)